# Having trouble assigning user input to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the syntax

```
name = input(' Enter name: ') 
print("hello " + name)
```

but every time I try to use a string with the name variable in it it says "name is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2, use `raw_input`:

```
name = raw_input(' Enter name: ')
```

Python 2's `input` function is basically Python 3's `eval(input(..))`

Python 3, python 2's `input` is removed,

Only keeping `raw_input` which is renamed to `input`

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x, `input` tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression. You want to use the `raw_input` function instead:

```
# input('...') is equivalent to eval(raw_input('...'))
name = raw_input(' Enter name: ')
```

However, if you are just starting out, you *should* be using Python 3, where the `input` function behaves like Python 2's `raw_input` function. (There is no function that automatically tries to evaluate the string; it was considered a bad design choice to provide such a function.)